# Windows 8 Reader with passworded PDF

Tags: windows-8, pdf

I have a PDF file that is password protected to prevent modifications.  Foxit or Adobe readers will open the file for viewing with no problem.  However, the Windows 8 Reader program asks for the password to be entered.  Is there any way to read the file in Windows 8 Reader without entering the password?

Comment: If you are stuck with Windows 8, then you could save the file without a password.

Comment: 1. That sounds like a bug in Windows 8 Reader. I'd suggest filing a bug report with Microsoft. 2. Keying the PDF file accomplishes *nothing*. Since the PDF can be read without knowing the password, the restriction can be removed without knowing the password.

Comment: *How* is the PDF password protected? A [**user password**](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsu/g/pdf-user-password.htm) restricts opening of the document, whereas an [**owner password**](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/erroro/g/pdf-owner-password.htm) is used to set document restrictions. The latter by itself should not cause a password prompt in any reader when the PDF is opened.